# Differences between random variables $X^2$ and $XX$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

For example, let $X$ be a random variable - tosses of a coin H = 1, T = 2. 

So $P[X = 1] = \frac{1}{2} = P[X = 2]$

Let be $Y_1 = X^2$ and $Y_2 = XX$.

Do I understand it properly, that in first case we toss only one coin and we raise the output to the second power, and in the second case we toss with two coins simultaneously and the output is product of the each one of them. So $Y_1 : \Omega \rightarrow R$ while $Y_2 : \Omega \times \Omega \rightarrow R$.

In the first case, we have only two events. We can get a Head, then $Y_1 = 1^2  =1$ or Tail, so $Y_2 = 2^2 = 4$. 

$P[Y_1 = 1] = P[X = 1] = \frac{1}{2} = P[X = 2] =P[Y_1 = 4]$.

In the second case, we have four events. HH, HT, TH, TT and $Y_2 = 1\cdot 1, 1\cdot 2, 2\cdot 1, 2\cdot 2 =1,2,2,4$ respectively. 
$P[Y_2 = 1] = P[(X = 1, X = 1)] = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$, 
$P[Y_2 = 2] = P[(X = 1, X = 2) \cup (X = 2, X = 1)] = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$,

$P[Y_2 = 2] = P[(X = 2, X = 2)] = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$.

It is common used notation?

Comment: This is a notation issue. I think that $X^2$ and $XX$ are the same, whereas if you had specified that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random variables then in general $X_1X_2 \ne X^2$, where $X$ remains a random variables